# ConfigParser no funciona en python

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo un programa que necesita comprobar un archivo de configuracion, este archivo se crea con un metodo asi que no deberia de dar problemas, el problema es que directamente no puedo acceder al dato, me da un error, pego el codigo y el output:

```
from configparser import ConfigParser
import os
config = ConfigParser()
config.read('config.cfg')
def Loggin():
    if (os.path.exists("config.cfg")):
        s = config.get('Bank', "bank name")
        print(s)
config = ConfigParser
prnt = config.get('Bank', 'bankn')
print("prnt")
```

output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/desarrollo-mac/Desktop/Programacion/Python/BankingApp/Loggin.py", line 10, in <module>
    config.get('Bank', 'bankn')
TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'option'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

el problema es que donde esta el config.get('bank', "bankname") el bankname es la opcion, la seccion es bank, no se como arreglarlo y estoy en el punto de que si no lo arreglo lanzo el ordenador por la ventana, llevo casi 3 horas buscando por que me pide la "opcion" cuando ya se la he dado, no se si es cosa del interpreter o algo (tengo un mac para programar ya que me propuse tambien aprender desarrollo movil y sacar apps para iOS)

Answer (score 0):

```
from configparser import ConfigParser
import os
config = ConfigParser()
config.read('config.cfg')
def Loggin():
    if (os.path.exists("config.cfg")):
        s = config.get('Bank', "bank name")
        print(s)
config = ConfigParser   ##ERROR: ESTAS SOBREESCRIBIENDO LA VARIABLE config
prnt = config.get('Bank', 'bankn')
print("prnt")
```

En la antepenultima linea estas pasando `ConfigParser` (la clase o función del modulo que importaste) a la variable `config` por tanto `config` pierde todo el contenido de tu archivo *"config.cfg"*, simplemente elimina esa linea y se quitara dicho error.

Espero haber sido de ayuda~

Comment: Es preferible dar un comentario, no veo la necesidad de una respuesta, no todas las preguntas se resuelven en respuestas :)

Comment: Muchas gracias, pues menudo error mas tonto he tenido jajajajajaja (no es una buena practica dedicarse a duplicar comandos), te agradezco la ayuda, efectivamente el problema esta solucionado :D